# Getting value from JSON when it is an object in an array in an object in an array - if that makes sense?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, iteration

I have been working on displaying values from a JSON feed and - **with a great deal of thanks** to help on the many previous posts I have read here - I can now write (display in browser) all the values of my objects in the main array BUT for the values of the 'name' objects which are 'nested' in an array > object > array > object > proprty:value structure (as below).  Wondering if anyone might me kind enough to help me find a way to interate and display this level successfully - I feel I have run out of ideas on it at the moment :-(

Very thankful for an ideas.  I have been using standard JavaScript not JQuery I should add.

```
var foo=[ 
    {
        "subjects": 
        [
            "A1",
            "SB2"
        ],
        "title": "Box World",
        "first_pub": "2013-12",
        "characters": 
        [
            {
                "name": 
                {
                    "given": "Maxwell",
                    "honourific": "",
                    "family": "Smart"
                },
                "id": "MS34"
            }, 
            {
                "name": 
                {
                    "given": "Samantha",
                    "honourific": "",
                    "family": "Stevens"
                },
                "id": "SS81"
            } // end creators object 2
        ],
        "publisher": "Galactic Publishing"
    },
    {
        "subjects": 
        [
            "A133",
            "PB82"
        ],
        "title": "Octonautica",
        "first_pub": "2010",
        "characters": 
        [
            {
                "name": 
                {
                    "given": "Peso",
                    "honourific": "Doctor",
                    "family": ""
                },
                "id": "MS34"
            },
            {
                "name": 
                {
                    "given": "Barnacle",
                    "honourific": "Captain",
                    "family": ""
                },
                "id": "SS82"
                } 
            ],
        "publisher": "Neptune House"
    }   
]


var obj_set = foo ;

for (var key in obj_set) {
   document.write("\<h3\> Publication " + key + "\<\/h3\>" );
   var obj = obj_set[key];
   document.write("\<ol\>");

   for (var prop in obj) {
      document.write("\<li\>" + prop + " = " + obj[prop] + "\<\/li\>" );
   }
   document.write("\<\/ol\>");

}   
//END MAIN KEY LOOP
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for iterating over the objects in the main array ?

Comment: @techfoobar I have added it to example now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var i, j;

// iterate over main array foo
for (i=0; i<foo.length; i++) {

    // iterate over characters array
    for(j=0; j<foo[i].characters.length; j++) {

        // each item contains an object "name"
        var name = foo[i].characters[j].name;

        console.log(name.honorific + ' ' + name.given + ' ' + name.family);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this after meeting and get back to you.  Thanks for your time @techfoobar

Comment: honorific and honourific need to match I should add for anyone reading this in future there is UK/USA spelling difference to match one way or another